# Prove the existence of uniformly distributed sequence of reals in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

> A sequence of reals $\{x_n\}$ in $[0,1]$ is uniformly distributed iff for every $a<b$ in [0,1], $$\lim_{n\to\infty}[\sum_{j=1}^n 1_{(a,b]}(x_j)]/n=b-a$$Prove that such a sequence exists. (Hint: Show that it suffices to show the above result holds for rational values $a$ and $b$.

Here is my approach:

Take $a<b, a,b\in [0,1]$. Let $\{x_j\}$ be a sequence of real numbers in $[0,1]$.

Define random variables $X_j=1_{(a,b]}(x_j)$, thus getting a sequence of random variables $\{X_j\}$. Then $P(X_j=1)=b-a, P(X_j=0)=1-(b-a)$ for every $j$, and they should be independent since $x_j\in (a,b]$ for any $j$ should be independent events. Then we get $E(X_j)=b-a$ for every $j$. Define, $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^n X_j$ and we get $\frac{S_n}{n}\to b-a$ almost surely by Strong Law of Large Numbers, which is the condition we want to show.

Now I have two questions:

1. Is my approach to this question correct? I'm a bit unsure that such random variables should exist in [0,1] though I feel that they should. Is this something I need to prove separately?
2. After I got through the question, I realized that I didn't use the hint at all, and I think the hint comes into play because the convergence in Strong Law of Large Numbers is ***almost surely***. Therefore I need to take care of the null sets where the above result doesn't hold, but I'm a bit stumped on how to do that, and not sure how to show that it "suffices" to prove the above for rational $a,b$.

I would like some feedback on my proof and help on the remaining questions that I have! Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem (not a proof you were asked for)

Comment: @EthanBolker I am unsure how that relates here :/

Comment: It is another way to think about equidistribution so I thought the  comment possibly useful.

Comment: @EthanBolker I'll give it a read, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Lemma.** $(x_j)$ is equidistributed if and only if, for each rationals $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$,
>
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{(a, b]}(x_j) = b-a. \tag{*} $$

*Proof.* Assume that $\text{(*)}$ holds for all rationals $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$. We want to show that $\text{(*)}$ holds for any *reals* $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$. To this end, we adopt the usual squeezing argument.

- Choose $a_k, b_k  \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$ such that $a_k \uparrow a$ and $b_k \downarrow b$ as $k \to \infty$. Then $\mathbf{1}_{(a, b]}(x) \leq \mathbf{1}_{(a_k, b_k]}(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and so, for each fixed $k$,

  $$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{(a, b]}(x_j)
  \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{(a_k, b_k]}(x_j) = b_k - a_k. $$

  Letting $k \to \infty$ shows that

  $$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{(a, b]}(x_j)
  \leq b - a. $$
- In this time, we choose $a_k, b_k \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0, 1]$ such that $a_k \downarrow a$ and $b_k \uparrow b$ as $k \to \infty$. Then, as before,

  $$ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{(a, b]}(x_j)
  \geq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{(a_k, b_k]}(x_j) = b_k - a_k $$

  and letting $k \to \infty$ gives

  $$ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{(a, b]}(x_j)
  \geq b - a. $$

Combining two estimates shows that $\text{(*)}$ does hold as required. ////

---

Let $(U_j)$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. Then for each rationals $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$, SLLN tells that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{(a, b]}(U_j) = b-a \quad \mathbb{P}\text{-a.s.}$$

So, if we consider the event

$$ \Omega_0 := \bigg\{ \omega : \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{(a, b]}(U_j(\omega)) = b-a \text{ for all } a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ with } 0 \leq a < b \leq 1 \bigg\}, $$

then $\Omega_0$ is the countable intersection of events having full probability, hence $\mathbb{P}[\Omega_0] = 1$. Moreover, by Lemma, for each $\omega \in \Omega_0$ the sequence $(U_j(\omega))_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is equidistributed. So by setting $x_j = U_j(\omega)$ for any choice of $\omega \in \Omega_0$, we obtain an equidistributed sequence.

---

As a totally different approach, one may give a concrete example. Indeed, choose $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and set $x_n = \alpha n \text{ mod } 1$. Weyl's criterion immediately tells that $(x_j)$ is equidistributed over $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For the second approach, I'm new to probability and don't know about Weyl's criterion :/. With that said, I have a couple questions: 1). Does my choice of random variables work as well? I was under the impression that the mean of our random variables should be $b-a$, but if $U_j$ are uniform on $[0,1]$, their mean is 0.5 isn't it? 2.) Could you elaborate why it suffices to show this for rationals, and how to prove that it suffices to show for rationals? Thank you.

Comment: @Sank, Notice that $$ \mathbf{1}_{(a, b]}(U_j) = \begin{cases} 1, & U_j \in (a, b] \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$ is a Bernoulli random variable with the parameter $b-a$.

Comment: Ah, I see that. How can I extend $U_j$'s to a sequence of reals $\{x_n\}$, is that just by evaluating $U_j$'s at given points? Also, I'm still bit unsure why it suffices to show that the above is true for rational $a,b$. I believe your proof after "So we have" shows that it suffices (correct me if I'm wrong), but I'm not sure why that is true, or why we need that :/

Comment: @Sank, I expanded my answer. :)

Comment: I understand now! We were concerned with possibly having an uncountable union of null sets (which may not be null together) if we work with reals only right? But by limiting the argument to the rationals, we get that $\Omega_0$ is a countable intersection, which means that ${\Omega_0}^c$ is a countable union, thus null itself as well?